How to solve issue with XSLT XPath with JDK11?
My existing product uses XSL transformation to convert XML to ReqIF which works well with Eclipse 4.6.3 and JDK 8.
Recently we upgraded to Eclipse 4.23 and JDK 11.0.22 (java version "11.0.22" 2024-01-16 LTS).
Also, we set below limits since those are introduced in JDK 11.
System.setProperty("jdk.xml.xpathExprGrpLimit", "0");
System.setProperty("jdk.xml.xpathExprOpLimit", "0");
System.setProperty("jdk.xml.xpathTotalOpLimit", "0");

While testing XSL transformation, I found the XSL transformation is not correct. JDK 11 release notes here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11all-relnotes.html mentions:
*There are two known issues:
An XPath expression that contains a short form of the parent axis ".." can return incorrect results. See JDK-8284920 for details. *
However, [JDK-8284920] (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8284920) is resolved. So, I should not get the transformation issue with not detecting the correct XPath.
Is there any issue other that above which I should be looking at?
I am using ".." in XPath to get parent. I would appreciate any pointers in this regard. Thanks!

You do know that  .. is short for parent::node()? https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev

@michael.hor257k yes, I know that. And it is working well with JDK 8. Exact same code is not working with JDK11.

To narrow down the problem, please answer the following questions even if these are not options you can apply: please provide a minimal reproducible example that works with Java 8, but causing this issue with Java 11; can the issue reproduced with Java 17 and 21?; is replacing .. with parent::node() a workaround for this issue?
